# How can I get the IP address of the caller in a Jersey 2.25.1 application?

Tags: jersey-2.0, jetty-9

I've tried the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280491/how-to-get-ip-from-containerrequestcontext-jersey-2-1) without luck: As the comments in the answer there mentions the `HttpServletRequest` is just `null`.

This is my filter:

```
public void myFilter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException 
  {
   // I don't see a way to get the IP address from the ContainerRequestContext
 }
```

If I try to use `@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest`, as the answer in the other question suggests, I just get a `NullPointerException`.

Another similar question: [How to get source address / ip from inside ContainerResponseFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196298/how-to-get-source-address-ip-from-inside-containerresponsefilter)

Comment: How are you registering the filter?

Comment: In my test I'm using `resourceConfig.register(MyFilter.class)`. In my app it's just included (because the class is annotated with `@Provider` and `Priority`?).

Comment: So is it in your test, is that where it's null, or in the app, or in both?

Comment: In the test. I'll confirm tomorrow that it's in the app as well.

Comment: Are you using the Jersey test framework?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for digging into what I'm doing. I'll provide a reproducible example as soon as I'm able.

Comment: After a bunch of testing (and help from you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386360/jersey2-unit-testing-httpservletrequest-is-null) it looks like my test setup was wrong. I chose to simply mock the httpServletRequest in our tests for now, as I can see that it does its job when our API is started as normal. Do you know of a way to make it work when we're using `jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty`?

Comment: [Doesn't look like they want to add support for it](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2764).

Comment: Could I ask your advice on what you would do? Mock the httpServletRequests in tests, or use grizzly instead of jetty?

Comment: If you are only using the servlet request in a couple places, just mocking is OK. If you are using Jetty for the app, might be better to just use the jetty container. Though I don't think there would be any problem using the grizzly container to test.

Comment: I posted an answer but if you would like to explain it then I'll choose your answer instead. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The nullpointerexception only occured in our tests. [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) helped me realize that injecting `HttpServletRequest` won't work as long as we're using `jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty` for our tests (see for example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2764 or https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3092). If we had used something like `GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory`, then injecting the `HttpServletRequest` would work since we then would have a `ServletDeploymentContext`.

We went for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973277/problems-running-jerseytest-when-dealing-with-httpservletresponse/26609306#26609306) in our tests, i.e. just mocking the `HttpServletRequest` where needed.